# Copy array in reverse

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse

I would like to copy an array in reverse order to the end of the same array and at the same time change the algebraic sign of the values.

It's something like that:

```
void foo()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for(int = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }

    //Now i want the values in vec to be copied to the end in reverse order.
    //I would like to have something like that :
    std::copy(std::end(vec), std::begin(vec), std::back_inserter(vec))

    //so now vec should look like: 0 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 0
    //But I want: 0 1 2 3 4 -4 -3 -2 -1 -0

}
```

Is there a std standard function already existing, that I can tweak to do what I want (like partition_copy or something) or do I maybe have to use my own thing like std::for_each with an appropriate lambda function?

Comment: This seems like a job for [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine `std::transform` with reverse iterators:

```
vec.reserve(2 * vec.size());  // guarantee iterator validity

std::transform(std::rbegin(vec), std::rend(vec),
               std::back_inserter(vec), [](int n) { return -n; });
```

Comment: There is a problem wit reverse iterators (unless in VS2013). I've tried your code and it throws an assertion 'Expression: vector iterator not decrementable'. Looks like the iterator gets invalidated anyway. When i switch to forward iterator everything works.

BTW instead of lamda as the predicate one can use `std::negate` from functional

Comment: @teivaz: Did you `reserve` capacity?

Comment: @KerrekSB yes I did. And again, everything works with forward iterators.

Comment: @KerrekSB If I use another vector as a destination everything works fine with any type of iterators. Probably there is something wrong with the specific implementation of reverse iterators in the MSVC

Comment: @teivaz Are you using the actual std::vector::rbegin() method or the std::rbegin() version? The latter does not work for me either as I seem to be unable to use c++14 methods. Could that be an issue?

Comment: @FreddyKay I am using `std::rbegin()` but internally it calls `std::vector::rbegin()`. I've tried to use vector's rbegin explicitly but still the same.

Comment: @FreddyKay: Oh, right, the free functions were added only in C++14.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly push the items using for loop, only difference is that the second for loop will add the items in reverse order and that in changed sign.

```
void foo()
{
std::vector<int> vec;
int i;
for( i=0; i<5; i++ )        //Loop to Add Items
        vec.push_back(i);
for( i=4; i>=0; i-- )       //Loop to Add Items in Reverse Order with Signs Changed
        vec.push_back( i * -1 );
for( i=0; i<vec.size(); i++ )
        cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
}
```